# Which is a correct HTTP status code for "Error creating resource"?

Tags: authentication, http, error-code

I'm developing an application with authentication, and i need to provide a appropriate status code if there is any error when registering an user, for example a database-related error.

I've been researching but i haven't found an appropriate status code.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of all HTTP errors is to communicate the operation failed. To pick the right HTTP error, you need to know why it failed.

"database-related error" sounds like a server-side bug or problem, so this is likely just a 500.